# How to proxy requests from client to another server

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I am working on a mobile app that will get some information from 3rd party API. API only accepts requests from certain IPs, that's why I am trying to build a proxy server that will work like below:

```
A -> Mobile Clients (IP: 1.1.1.1)
B -> Proxy Server (IP: 2.2.2.2)
C -> 3rd Party API (myapisite.com/*)
```

Basically, every request from A to C needs to go through B since C only accepts requests from B's IP. I've tried to build it via HAProxy but couldn't manage with domain names. I need a routing mechanism like below:

```
HTTP requests to 2.2.2.2/myapi should be forwarded to myapisite.com/api
HTTP requests to 2.2.2.2/myotherapi should be forwarded to myapisite.com/otherapi
```

What would be the simplest solution? Right now, I am thinking about using Ubuntu as a proxy server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimal config

```
listen fe_http
  mode tcp
  timeout client  60s
  timeout connect 2s
  timeout server  5s
  bind :::80 v4v6
  server destservr myapisite.com:80 check
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a Front End dev and going through similar problem
like I have a react client app on Https, the BE is on http and I can't change the be, so I thought to either proxy the client calls or wrap the BE with an https wrapper
which would be faster, can you explain to me more about the steps you just mentioned and how to do them ?

Comment: Dear @ahmed-sarhan I strongly recommend to read the following blog posts https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy-ssl-termination/ https://www.haproxy.com/blog/send-user-to-the-same-backend-for-both-http-and-https/ . If you still have some questions please open a new Question because the answer then could be much larger then the comments